# What makes JSON or YAML syntax able to be sent "through the wire"?

Tags: json, ruby, serialization, yaml

```
require 'yaml'
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age
end
fred = Person.new
fred.name = "Fred Bloggs"
fred.age = 45
laura = Person.new
laura.name = "Laura Smith"

laura.age = 23
test_data = [ fred, laura ]
puts test_data.to_yaml

#YAML
- !ruby/object:Person
  age: 45
  name: Fred Bloggs
- !ruby/object:Person
  name: Laura Smith
  age: 23
```

This is an example of YAML serialization from a book that I am reading. I'm having trouble understanding what makes YAML syntax any different from normal ruby code for it to be saved/sent. If it were to be converted to binary as in "binary serialization" it would make sense to me as it would be able to be sent faster. If the point of serialization is to keep the state of an object in order and make it into a stream why not just make it a stream of its original order and syntax?

Comment: "*what makes YAML syntax any different from normal ruby code*" - Because the aim is to send **data**, not **code**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the question whether binary serialization would be faster: Yes, it would. If you are concerned about speed, YAML is not the tool you want – you should turn to other tools like [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org). YAML has been designed to be human readable.

So why send YAML instead of Ruby code? Well, for starters: Security. If one end sends Ruby code to the other end and the code gets evaluated there, this may easily turn into a vulnerability if an unauthorized third party finds a way to inject a message into this stream; it can lead to arbitrary code execution.

So let's assume we don't actually want to send arbitrary Ruby code. Instead, we want to send a subset which is a single expression which evaluates to the data we want to send. Incidentally, this is how JSON came into existence: As a subset of JavaScript evaluating to an object value.

Since JSON already exists, there is no point in inventing the wheel again basing some serialization language on Ruby, unless you want to add some feature missing from JSON¹. You would need to write a complete parser and emitter (note that you cannot simply use your Ruby implementation because, as described above, this will let an attacker execute arbitrary code). And JSON is already supported in a wide range of programming languages and ecosystems, making it an ideal data interexchange format if you value cross-platform compatibility.

So now the question remains what YAML offers in addition to JSON. Some argue that YAML syntax is far better readable than JSON, YMMV. But there are a number of features in YAML that make it superior to JSON:

- YAML has an extensible tagging system for annotation content with a type. Example from your code: `!ruby/object:Person`. This ensures that if you have a field in your data structure where differently typed values can occur, the receiving side immediately knows which type to use for deserialization. In JSON, you would need type inference (deducing the type from the value of the expression) to make that decision and that is not always possible².
- Data structures may contain cycles (e.g. ring lists, strongly connected graphs). These are difficult to serialize. YAML has built-in anchors and aliases, making it possible to reference a previously started node to denote a cyclic structure. JSON has no such thing. I assume it would be difficult to include this feature in a Ruby-based serialization language without adding features alien to Ruby itself.
- Lastly, and that's the answer to the question in the title, YAML has been designed for streaming (JSON to a far lesser extent). A YAML stream can contain any number of documents. This makes it possible to keep a stream open and wait for new data on the receiving side. In contrast, JSON expects the input to end after one object.

All of this does not mean that YAML (or JSON) is the one and only way to go. Don't have any cycles or heterogeneous fields in your data? You won't need anchors/aliases or tags! Don't need human-readable serialization? You can go with a binary format! JSON and YAML have been successful because their feature set pretty well mirrors the requirements in a lot of applications. Whether it is the right tool for your application is up to you to decide.

---

¹ There are surely projects that do exactly that for any number of reasons. The point I want to make is that in general, implementing proper (de-)serialization is an involved task and you usually want to use what's already there.

² You can, of course, extend your JSON schema so that every node has a structure like this:

```
{
  "type": "myType",
  "value": ...
}
```

But that would make the serialization pretty verbose.

Comment: Getting out of my league with this next question but if security was an issue wouldnt a human readable serialization method easily be reverse engineered?  Nice explanation though, cleared a lot up for me

Comment: Reverse engineering is not a security problem unless you consider *„security by obscurity“* a valid approach to system security.

Comment: For comparison: HTML is also a plain-text format but nowadays is typically transmitted via TLS (-> HTTPS) so it is not readable nor modifiable by any third party. You can do exactly the same with YAML.